# Fill the complete canvas but keep the bound fill area as it is like circle, rectangle

Tags: android, android-canvas

possible duplicate

Hello friends,

I creating paint application, I have problem in that. If I draw the rectangle without fill and or another like bound area and change the background color then rectangle fill area also change means whole canvas color will be filled with the new background color. How to keep the background or fill the canvas area which was not bound, here is the image

this is the initial image

[image]

after change the background color getting this result

[image]

but how to getting like this way

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
final Point p1 = new Point();
                p1.x=(int) x; //x co-ordinate where the user touches on the screen
                p1.y=(int) y; //y co-ordinate where the user touches on the screen  
 new TheTask(yourbitmap, p1, sourceColor,targetColor).execute();// use asyntask for efficiency

 class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    Bitmap bmp;
    Point pt;
    int replacementColor,targetColor;
    ProgressDialog pd;
 public TheTask(Bitmap bm,Point p, int sc, int tc)
 {
this.bmp=bm;
this.pt=p;
this.replacementColor=tc;
this.targetColor=sc;
pd= new ProgressDialog(context);
pd.setMessage("Filling....");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FloodFill f= new FloodFill();
        f.floodFill(bmp,pt,targetColor,replacementColor);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
pd.dismiss();
invalidate();
    }
```

Finally use a FloodFill algorithm to fill a closed area

```
    public class FloodFill {
public void floodFill(Bitmap  image, Point node, int targetColor,
        int replacementColor) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    int target = targetColor;
    int replacement = replacementColor;
    if (target != replacement) {
        Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
        do {
            int x = node.x;
            int y = node.y;
            while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                x--;
            }
            boolean spanUp = false;
            boolean spanDown = false;
            while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                    spanUp = true;
                } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                        && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                    spanUp = false;
                }
                if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                    queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                    spanDown = true;
                } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                        && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                    spanDown = false;
                }
                x++;
            }
        } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Link to screen shot with background changed http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2a9a891&s=6. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You can change background and fill the closed area with the color you want.

Comment: @TalhaQ you can't this answer and code is to solve a specific problem. If you are looking for code sorry that is not how this site works.

Comment: you are right but i cant find the mainactivity from where you initialize this code

Comment: @TalhaQ this code is not for you. its for solving specific problem posted by the question user. And nobody is going to give you complete code. that's not how stackoverflow works sorry

Comment: @TalhaQ try posting your problem as a new question and you might find an answer. But do not ask for complete code you will not get. you can dicuss how the site works @ meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: it not able to fill the particular object , it filling full screen @Raghunathan

Comment: @VigneshwaranT how am i suppose to know without looking at the code. Secondly you post your code

Answer (score 0):

here is the code (you have to bound the shape on touch event otherwise it change the color of shape works):

```
public class ttt extends View {
MyShape myShape;
public ttt(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myShape = new MyShape();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    myShape.setPaint(paint);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    myShape.onDraw(canvas);     
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        myShape.setPaint(paint);
        invalidate();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

class MyShape {
    private Paint paint;
    public MyShape() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawCircle(15, 15, 30, getPaint());
    }
    /**
     * @param paint the paint to set
     */
    public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
        this.paint = paint;
    }
    /**
     * @return the paint
     */
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I have set the paint object like this way and whatever shape I have drawn that style was set to only Stroke not the fill. If I set as fill and stroke then both color are same

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at using the clip region as in these 2 questions:

- [Using clipRect - explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331805/using-cliprect-explantion)
- [Canvas.clipPath(Path) not clipping as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672802/canvas-clippathpath-not-clipping-as-expected)

Depending on what you want to do, they may be useful.

I found your question because I didn't know what to google for, and the answer I wanted was not using Flood Fill.