# Draw on Picture in android

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-imageview

I was working on a custom imageview that can draw line on it, the problem is that the drawing area size is not exactly with the bitmap size.

For example, in the other app, it looks like:

[image]

However, in my app, it looks like

[image]

Here is my program, which seems the bitmap is not fit with the canvas. Thanks for helping

```
   public class DrawingView extends View {

    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;


    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    //setup drawing
    private void setupDrawing(){

        //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(15.0f);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    //size assigned to view
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    //draw the view - will be called after touch event
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher), 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //register user touches as drawing action
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        //respond to down, move and up events
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        //redraw
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    //update color
    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }

    //start new drawing
    public void startNew(){
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

And I found the similar tutorial code, the problem is that the touch event has bug, it count in the action bar and the rest UI element so the touching is weird. Recommend to have a look

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/DrawonPictureandsave.htm

So, the goal of this topic , is the solution of

1) draw-able image

2) zoom-able and pan-able(can use library) (when active zoom , zoom, when inactive zoom , draw)

can reference the screenshot 1 for the idea

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704205/how-to-draw-line-on-imageview-along-with-finger-in-android if it help

Comment: Please take a look at my answer @user782104

Comment: " the problem is that the touch event has bug " what bug do you really mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can avoid counting coordinates of other UI items in your sample by creation your own ImageView. Try this code for `Activity`:

```
public class DrawOnBitmapActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {

DrawableImageView choosenImageView;
Button choosePicture;
Button savePicture;

Bitmap bmp;
Bitmap alteredBitmap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    choosenImageView = (DrawableImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosenImageView);
    choosePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton);
    savePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.SavePictureButton);

    savePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    choosePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if (v == choosePicture) 
    {
        Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);
    } 
    else if (v == savePicture) 
    {
        if (alteredBitmap != null) 
        {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(3);
            contentValues.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Draw On Me");

            Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                    Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            try {
                OutputStream imageFileOS = getContentResolver()
                        .openOutputStream(imageFileUri);
                alteredBitmap
                        .compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, imageFileOS);
                Toast t = Toast
                        .makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
                    bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

            choosenImageView.setNewImage(alteredBitmap, bmp);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

You have to change `activity_main` layout slightly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Picture" android:id="@+id/ChoosePictureButton"/>
    <ru.pristalovpavel.drawonimage.DrawableImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ChoosenImageView">
    </ru.pristalovpavel.drawonimage.DrawableImageView>
     <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Picture" android:id="@+id/SavePictureButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and your custom `ImageView`:

```
public class DrawableImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener 
{
    float downx = 0;
    float downy = 0;
    float upx = 0;
    float upy = 0;

    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    Matrix matrix;

    public DrawableImageView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public DrawableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void setNewImage(Bitmap alteredBitmap, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap );
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        matrix = new Matrix();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

        setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) 
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
            downy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
            upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            invalidate();
            downx = upx;
            downy = upy;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0];//event.getX();
            upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1];//event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    final float[] getPointerCoords(MotionEvent e)
    {
        final int index = e.getActionIndex();
        final float[] coords = new float[] { e.getX(index), e.getY(index) };
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(getScrollX(), getScrollY());
        matrix.mapPoints(coords);
        return coords;
    }
}
```

All source code of the project in eclipse: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9_PokrJ2SoCZzRxSllMWTJmdms/view?usp=sharing)

**UPDATE:**

new source code for `DrawableImageView`!

More information is in [my blog](https://pristalovpavel.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/drawing-on-image-in-android/).

Comment: Thanks a lot , tried import the source code but seems the drawing area is not fit exactly to the picture, would you mind using some large picture and have a test

Comment: My fault! I have updated the answer. Just refresh `DrawableImageView`. As for me it works)

Comment: @user782104 In this zoom functionality is not there

Answer (score 1):

**KOTLIN SOLUTION FOR SAME (using anilanswer)**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import android.widget.ImageView


class CustomEditImageView : ImageView, OnTouchListener {
    var downx = 0f
    var downy = 0f
    var upx = 0f
    var upy = 0f
    lateinit var canvas: Canvas
    lateinit var paint: Paint
    lateinit var EditImagematrix: Matrix

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context,
        attrs
    ) {
        setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?,
        defStyleAttr: Int
    ) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        setOnTouchListener(this)
    }

    fun setNewImage(alteredBitmap: Bitmap, bmp: Bitmap) {
        canvas = Canvas(alteredBitmap)
        paint = Paint()
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN)
        paint.strokeWidth=18f
        EditImagematrix = Matrix()
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, EditImagematrix, paint)
        setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap)
    }

    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val action = event.action
        when (action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                downx = getPointerCoords(event)[0] //event.getX();
                downy = getPointerCoords(event)[1] //event.getY();
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0] //event.getX();
                upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1] //event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint)
                invalidate()
                downx = upx
                downy = upy
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                upx = getPointerCoords(event)[0] //event.getX();
                upy = getPointerCoords(event)[1] //event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
            }
            else -> {
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    fun getPointerCoords(e: MotionEvent): FloatArray {
        val index = e.actionIndex
        val coords = floatArrayOf(e.getX(index), e.getY(index))
        val matrix = Matrix()
        imageMatrix.invert(matrix)
        matrix.postTranslate(scrollX.toFloat(), scrollY.toFloat())
        matrix.mapPoints(coords)
        return coords
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
var bmp: Bitmap? = null
    var alteredBitmap: Bitmap? = null

var image = extras.getString(AppConstants.IMAGE_URI).toString()
                if (image.isNotEmpty()) {
                    val bmpFactoryOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
                    bmp = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(
                            File(image).inputStream(), null, bmpFactoryOptions
                        )

                    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
                    bmp = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream(
                            File(image).inputStream(), null, bmpFactoryOptions
                        )

                    alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        bmp!!.width,
                        bmp!!.height, bmp!!.config
                    )
                    editimageView.setNewImage(alteredBitmap!!, bmp!!)
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>


    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightalphablack"
        tools:context=".ui.activities.ImageViewActivity">

        <com.mynamespace.test.customviews.CustomEditImageView
            android:id="@+id/editimageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please take a look**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/enable_zoom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="disable zoom"/>

<com.rbt.zoomdraw.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/zoom_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_below="@+id/enable_zoom" />

<com.rbt.zoomdraw.DrawableView
    android:id="@+id/drawble_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/zoom_iv"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/zoom_iv" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button enableZoomBtn;
private DrawableView drawbleView;
private CustomImageView touchImageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawbleView = (DrawableView) findViewById(R.id.drawble_view);
    enableZoomBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enable_zoom);
    touchImageView = (CustomImageView) findViewById(R.id.zoom_iv);
    enableZoomBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.enable_zoom:
        if(enableZoomBtn.getText().equals("disable zoom")){
            touchImageView.setZoomEnable(false);
            drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(true);
            enableZoomBtn.setText("enable zoom");
        } else{
            touchImageView.setZoomEnable(true);
            drawbleView.setDrawingEnabled(false);
            enableZoomBtn.setText("disable zoom");
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**DrawableView.java**

```
public class DrawableView extends View {
public int width;
public  int height;
private boolean isEditable;
private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint;
private Paint canvasPaint;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private int paintColor = Color.RED;
public DrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    setupDrawing();
}
public DrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    this.height = h;
    this.width = w;
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}
private void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setDither(true);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
}
public void setDrawingEnabled(boolean isEditable){
    this.isEditable = isEditable;
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(isEditable){
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath = new Path();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    } else{
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
}
```

**CustomImageView**

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
Matrix matrix;
// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
private boolean zoomEnable= true;
// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 5f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
Context context;
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}
public void setZoomEnable(boolean status){
    zoomEnable = status;
}
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(zoomEnable){
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled

            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
     }
    fixTrans();
  }
}
```

**All the very best**

Comment: I have tried to implement this. After some minor issues (I am a Java Newbie), I sort of got it working. If I zoom after drawing, the drawing does not change size, just the background image. I've tried to copy the ontouch content from CustomImageView into DrawableView onTouchEvent (and fixing all references) but it still doesn't scale. Help here would be very much appreciated, thank you.