# How to draw over an image that is part of a gallery

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-viewpager, draw

Is there any tutorial and/or library that helps you draw over an image that is part of a gallery [ViewPager] that opens up on a Dialog. I need something like Messenger's "remix" button.

[image: Messenger's Remix Button]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209532/draw-on-picture-in-android)

Comment: being a member for over 2 years ., you should know that it is off-topic to ask for both - library or tutorial here.

Comment: May be you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209532/draw-on-picture-in-android)