# How to make sketch on android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working for a project on android studio. I need a kind of map, Suppose that I gonna create some buildings and colour of this buildings will able to change. To put it simply, I want to print them red and green. Colour will represent this building available or not. I dont know what can i do about it. I am ok all suggest about this problem, library, open source project, idea whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canvas for painting and sketching in Android.

You can refer this link-
[Draw on Picture in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209532/draw-on-picture-in-android)

Comment: I think i couldnt explain what i mean. I mean i need a kind of map like google maps but it includes only local place. I cant use google or yandex because this place inside of a building so i need to create. Infact i can draw by photoshop or similar programs but problem here is that i gonna need to change color of items on this map. Someones will be red and the others will be green. So i have to detect them and seperate to each other. If you know any library or open source project like that i gonna be glad.