# How to paint on Bitmap using canvas drawPath or Path? I tried several tutorials but failed

Tags: java, android, canvas

So this is my current code which uses canvas **drawLine**, where I'm trying to modify it into **drawPath**.

My Declared Variables in Main Activity :

```
ImageView imageResult;
final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;

Paint paint;
Uri source;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Path path;
```

My code in On Create method :

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawing_board);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    //result is the ID of imageview
    imageResult = findViewById(R.id.result);

    //The user will select Images on gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
```

Where selected image pass into imageResult variable and then converted into bitmap, and that bitmap will be place into the canvas :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bitmap tempBitmap;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RQS_IMAGE1:
                source = data.getData();

                try {
                    //tempBitmap is Immutable bitmap,
                    //cannot be passed to Canvas constructor
                    tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                            getContentResolver().openInputStream(source));

                    Bitmap.Config config;
                    if (tempBitmap.getConfig() != null) {
                        config = tempBitmap.getConfig();
                    } else {
                        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    }

                    //bitmap is Mutable bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            tempBitmap.getWidth(),
                            tempBitmap.getHeight(),
                            config);

                    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                    imageResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is the method where I get the touch points of users finger and put the canvas.drawLine inside of motion events. So then, they can paint on the canvas where the Imageview is placed :

```
    private float mX,mY;
public void paintOn_Image(){

imageResult.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
           float ratioWidth = (float)bitmap.getWidth()/(float)v.getWidth();
           float ratioHeight = (float)bitmap.getHeight()/(float)v.getHeight();

                canvas.drawLine(
                        mX * ratioWidth,
                        mY * ratioHeight,
                        x * ratioWidth,
                        y * ratioHeight,
                        paint);

                imageResult.invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                ratioWidth = (float) bitmap.getWidth() / (float) v.getWidth();
                ratioHeight = (float)bitmap.getHeight()/(float)v.getHeight();

                canvasMaster.drawLine(
                        mX * ratioWidth,
                        mY * ratioHeight,
                        x * ratioWidth,
                        y * ratioHeight,
                        paint);

                imageResult.invalidate();

                mX = x;
                mY = y;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                ratioWidth = (float) bitmapMaster.getWidth() / (float) v.getWidth();
                ratioHeight = (float)bitmapMaster.getHeight()/(float)v.getHeight();

                canvasMaster.drawLine(
                        x * ratioWidth,
                        y * ratioHeight,
                        x * ratioWidth,
                        y * ratioHeight,
                        paint);

                imageResult.invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Here's what I've done so far.
In the motionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,ACTION_MOVE & ACTION_UP, I change this :

```
                    canvas.drawLine(
                        mX * ratioWidth,
                        mY * ratioHeight,
                        x * ratioWidth,
                        y * ratioHeight,
                        paint);

                imageResult.invalidate();
                break;
```

Into this :

```
                path.moveTo(mX*ratioWidth,mY*ratioHeight);
                path.lineTo(x*ratioWidth,y*ratioHeight);
                path.moveTo(mX*ratioWidth,y*ratioHeight);
                path.lineTo(x*ratioWidth,mY*ratioHeight);
                canvas.drawPath(path,paintDraw);
                imageResult.invalidate();

                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                imageResult.invalidate();
                break;
```

*But the application is crashing when the user touch the canvas :(*

How can I paint on canvas using Path? Is the calculation **incorrect**?

The reason why I'm trying to change it into path is we can't **undo** the
drawLine after painting into the canvas. So if you have solution to
**undo/clear/remove** the drawLine, that will also work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot of documentation and tutorials and informations in this forum.

Just Create DrawableView and CustomImageview instead of dwelling on Imageview.

[Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250486/19026761)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).