# How to select the image by drawing a line around it in android?

Tags: android, canvas, line, draw

I am creating a simple free hand drawing app. In my layout, i have two images placed. I need to select the correct image, by drawing a free hand circle around the image. As i am new to android, i don't know the correct way to do it. I tried some ways to draw free hand drawings like, calling a drawing view class and using the onDraw method to paint the path using canvas, but for that i had to kept my setContentView() to drawing view class. But I want to use my layout with images as setContentView() and make free hand drawings to draw around the images. Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704205/how-to-draw-line-on-imageview-along-with-finger-in-android?

Comment: ya. I had seen that. From that I can set background and draw lines in the foreground layout. But also I need to select a particular image from a line or path drawn around it. Can i get a solution for image selection through path drawn around it?