# Cannot Generate Texture From Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, draw, flood-fill

I am using `floodfill` algorithm to fill a black white picture with specific color with user touches.
I used this Question to use floodfill algorithm : [How to use flood fill algorithm in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968412/how-to-use-flood-fill-algorithm-in-android)

the problem is sometime(whey i want to fill fast) I get `Cannot Generate Texture From Bitmap` error and  `mBitmap.getPixel(x, y)` returns 0 and filling will be stop!

I can use `copyPixelsToBuffer ( pictureBuffer )` instead of `getPixel()` method According to last post of this link : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1338782/java/general-java/java-mobiles/android/openglrenderer-cannot-generate-texture-from-bitmap/

But i do not know How to Change current Code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Solved that according to Shubhadeep Chaudhuri answer in below link :

> Somebody ported J. Dunlap's Queue-Linear Flood Fill Algorithm to
>   android here. I've tried it and it's pretty fast.
>
> I've modified the copyImage() method which originally makes use of a
>   class called Utilities which the author hasn't provided.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426163/401403