# Canvas.clipPath(Path) not clipping as expected

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, image-clipping

I'm trying to clip a canvas drawing operation to an arc-shaped wedge. However, I'm not getting the intended result after setting the clipping path to the canvas.

For illustration, here is what I'm doing:

[image]

```
path.reset();

//Move to point #1
path.moveTo(rect.centerX(), rect.centerY());

//Per the documentation, this will draw a connecting line from the current
//position to the starting position of the arc (at 0 degrees), add the arc
//and my current position now lies at #2.
path.arcTo(rect, 0, -30);

//This should then close the path, finishing back at the center point (#3)
path.close();
```

This works, and when I simply draw this path (`canvas.drawPath(path, paint)`) it draws the wedge as shown above. However, when I set this path as the canvas's clipping path and draw into it:

```
//I've tried it with and without the Region.Op parameter
canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.REPLACE);
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
```

I get the following result instead (the wedge is left just to show reference):

[image]

So it instead seems to clip to the bounding rect of the `Path`, and not the `Path` itself. Any ideas what's happening here?

**EDIT** Just as an update, I've found a much more efficient way of doing this that allows for hardware acceleration. First, draw the entire image (that you'd be clipping) into an offscreen bitmap. Make a `BitmapShader` using this `Bitmap`, set that shader to a `Paint`, then draw the wedge path using that `Paint` object:

```
drawMyBitmap(bitmap);
Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setShader(shader);

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawArc(rect,         //The rectangle bounding the circle
                   startAngle,   //The angle (CW from 3 o'clock) to start
                   sweepAngle,   //The angle (CW from 3 o'clock) of the arc
                   true,         //Boolean of whether to draw a filled arc (wedge)
                   paint         //The paint with the shader attached
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you using HC or above or otherwise using hardware acceleration? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html.  If so, clipPath is unsupported and problematic.

Comment: @Simon: Oh my god. Heh. Sadly I've been referring to that document a lot this week, but I totally overlooked that. Disabling HW Accel worked perfectly! If you'll post this as an answer I'll accept it. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Good luck.

Comment: Beautiful question!

Comment: How exactly do you accomplish this?: "First, draw the entire image (that you'd be clipping) into an offscreen bitmap"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using HC or above or otherwise using hardware acceleration?

If so, clipPath is unsupported and problematic.

[developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html).

Comment: That was the problem. :) Moved the clipping part of the drawing operation into an offscreen bitmap, then drew it back to the HW accelerated canvas and it works like a charm! Thanks again!

Comment: @kcoppock That sounds a bit backwards. Why don't you just convert the view's layer type into software, and still do your drawing in `onDraw()`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That would have made more sense. :) I was a bit unfamiliar with that at the time. I've edited in the new way that I'm handling this problem now, thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 3):

OP's question is specifically about using a clipping region and has been answered by @Simon. Bear in mind, however, that there's a more straightforward way of drawing a filled arc:

Create a `Paint`:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

When drawing, simply draw the path:

```
canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```