# Fill with Color on Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an image which include 10 boxes on my image view. When I click the one of boxes I want to change color of box (fill with color). How do I do that? Should I use Surface View or something else?

Update:
I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723590/fill-the-complete-canvas-but-keep-the-bound-fill-area-as-it-is-like-circle-rect/12777805#12777805). But if I use AsyncTask the code does not work. If I use a normal class the code works. I do not know why but I think problem is related with invalidate().

Comment: What are those boxes? are they Views? or are they party of your image?

Comment: My image consist of 10 boxes like chessboard

Comment: please provide some code what you tried for it.. or xml what you are using. as you mentioned you have imageview which contains 10 boxes can you provide that?

Comment: My image is: http://i43.tinypic.com/330elwm.jpg

Comment: And my xml: http://pastie.org/8009984

Comment: I think this is going to be quite complicated, because the boxes are in an image file. You could load it into a Bitmap type and use the canvas to draw or fill the corresponding rectangles. I think it would be more easy to create 2 image files: One for a colored box and one for a white box. Then you can insert the images using a table layout for example and switch between the two image files as necessary.

Comment: @Chris623, if I create colored box for each colors, then there are hundreds of bitmaps. Actually my problem is that: I don't know how I should use invalidate() function in AsyncTask. Because if I use normal class for this operation everything work well.