# Undo Redo with FloodFill android

Tags: android, flood-fill

I am implementing floodfill using [Floodfill algorithm in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197416/floodfill-algorithm-in-android) and for paint operation we can implement undo redo with the path objects but how do we achieve this for floodfill operation without DrawingCache? Is there a way I can get Path object when I do the FloodFill operation?

Comment: The easiest way would be to save/cache hard-copies of the floodfill input (Bitmap image) or the underlying Bitmap model in a state-cache structure e.g. a serializable queue. If you want to have a undo-function for every step the floodfill algorithm does, you have to edit this algorithm...

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how can I change the algorithm as I want to be able to undo every step and not create multiple copies of bitmap.

Comment: In the algorithm before: 

image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);

you could safe a deep/hard copy of image in a Undo-Queue.
This assumes, that you have to repeat the whole algorithm again, because the state (the current node) won't be saved this way...

Except you have some event-listener on the Bitmap it won't update the canvas automatically on every setPixel anyway...?

Comment: Won't it give out of memory exception if I keep on saving the copy of bitmaps in a queue and don't undo for a while?

Comment: Yes it would, that was just the basic idea...
Apparently a Bitmap can be created out of those simple information?

createBitmap(int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)

Returns a !!!immutable!!! bitmap with the specified width and height, with each pixel value set to the corresponding value in the colors array.

So it would be okay to just save (in worst case serialize and save in file) those parts: int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config

Comment: How to get the colors[] of bitmap ?

Comment: Regarding https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html
with getPixels(int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)
Returns in pixels[] a copy of the data in the bitmap.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: @zek54 have you found solution? because I have same situation !!!